# Matrix Derivations-Research

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

First off, I know that this problem is extremely long and can be intimidating. I have put a lot of work and thought into it.

In reference to what  loup blanc has responded with, I am not dismissing his answer, I just do not understand it. Please either respond according to my what, or elaborate on a different approach with as much elaboration as I have put in please.

$DT_3(R)$ is the upper triangular matrix with the diagonal being the same element over the real field R, for example $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\0&a&d\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}$ where $a,b,c,d ∈R$. Based on this, we will show how the following conditions hold true.
  Determine all mappings s.t $DT_3(R) \to DT_3(R)$  and the following conditions are true:

$(1) d(A+B)=d(A)+d(B)$
$(2) d(αA)=αd(A)$  where $α$  is a scalar
$(3) d(AB)=Ad(B)+d(A)B$

Let's suppose  $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\0&a&d\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}$ $\to \begin{bmatrix}f(a,b,c,d)&g(a,b,c,d)&h(a,b,c,d)\\0&f(a,b,c,d)&i(a,b,c,d)\\0&0&f(a,b,c,d)\end{bmatrix}$  where $f,g,h,i$ from $R^4 \to R$

Also, suppose
 $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\0&a&d\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\\0&x&v\\0&0&x\end{bmatrix}$

We will now work on finding the restrictions on f,g,h,i s.t. the above conditions, starting with condition 
$(1) d(A+B)=d(A)+d(B)$

therefore
$d(A+B)=\begin{bmatrix}f(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)&g(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)&h(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)\\0&f(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)&i(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)\\0&0&f(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)\end{bmatrix}$

This is the left side of the equation. Now to show the right side

$d(A)+d(B)=\begin{bmatrix}f(a,b,c,d)+f(x,y,z,v)&g(a,b,c,d)+g(x,y,z,v)&h(a,b,c,d)+h(x,y,z,v)\\0&f(a,b,c,d)+f(x,y,z,v)&i(a,b,c,d)+i(x,y,z,v)\\0&0&f(a,b,c,d)+f(x,y,z,v)\end{bmatrix}$

Taking each of the elements in the above matrix and adding the respective elements together, we get the following equations:

$f(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)=f(a,b,c,d)+f( x,y,z,v)$
$g(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)=g(a,b,c,d)+g( x,y,z,v)$
$h(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)=h(a,b,c,d)+h( x,y,z,v)$
$i(a+x,b+y,c+z,d+v)=i(a,b,c,d)+i( x,y,z,v)$

Therefor f,g,h,i preservee addition.

Condition (2) states $d(αA)=αd(A)$  where $α$  is a scalar. We will take matrix A from above and multiply it by a scalar. We will show the left side of the equal sign first, then we will show the right side.

$d(αA)=\begin{bmatrix}f(αa,αb,αc,αd)&g(αa,αb,αc,αd)&h(αa,αb,αc,αd)\\0&f(αa,αb,αc,αd)&i(αa,αb,αc,αd)\\0&0&f(αa,αb,αc,αd)\end{bmatrix}$

The right-hand side will then be

$αd(A)=\begin{bmatrix}αf(a,b,c,d)&αg(a,b,c,d)&αh(a,b,c,d)\\0&αf(a,b,c,d)&αi(a,b,c,d)\\0&0&αf(a,b,c,d)\end{bmatrix}$

Thus,

$f(αa,αb,αc,αd)=αf(a,b,c,d)$
$g(αa,αb,αc,αd)=αg(a,b,c,d)$
$h(αa,αb,αc,αd)=αh(a,b,c,d)$
$i(αa,αb,αc,αd)=αi(a,b,c,d)$

Therfore f,g,h,i are linear transformations

(3)  Now to show how condition (3) holds. We will be using matrix A and matrix B from above. As before, we will start with proving the left side of the equal sign, and then progress to proving the right side, therefore showing that condition (3) is true as well.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}(a&b&c\\0&a&d\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}$      $B=\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\\0&x&v\\0&0&x\end{bmatrix}$

$d(AB)=Ad(B)+d(A)B$  $\to$

$\begin{bmatrix}f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)&g(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)&h(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)\\0&f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)&i(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)\\0&0&f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)))\end{bmatrix}$

=$\begin{bmatrix}(af(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)x &ag(x,y,z,v)+bf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)y+g(a,b,c,d)x&ah(x,y,z,v)+bi(x,y,z,v)+cf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)z+g(a,b,c,d)v+h(a,b,c,d)\\0&af(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)x&ai(x,y,z,v)+df(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)v+i(a,b,c,d)x\\0&0&0)\end{bmatrix}$

Since the above matrices equal each other, we can say that corresponding entries are equal to each other as well. From this point, we will match up each corresponding element in the matrices and set them equal to each other, formulating a set of 4 equations.

$Equation 1: f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)= af(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)x$
$Equation 2: g(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=$ $ag(x,y,z,v)+bf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)y+g(a,b,c,d)x$
$Equation3:h(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=ah(x,y,z,v)+bi(x,y,z,v)+cf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)z+g(a,b,c,d)v+h(a,b,c,d)x$
$Equation4:i(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=ai(x,y,z,v)+df(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)v+i(a,b,c,d)x$

Now that we have equations to work with, we would like to then simplify these equations so that we may then be able solve them. We will start with equation 1.

$Equation 1: f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)= af(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)x$

Starting with the left hand side, 
$f(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)$
$=f[(ax,0,0,0)+(0,ay+bx,0,0)+(0,0,az+bv+cx,0)+(0,0,0,av+dx)]$
$=axf(1,0,0,0)+ay+bx(0,1,0,0)+az+bv+cx(0,0,1,0)+av+dx(0,0,0,1)]$

If we assign $f(1,0,0,0)=a_1,  f(0,1,0,0)=a_2, f(0,0,1,0)=a_3, f(0,0,0,1)=a_4$, we then have the following equation: 
$axa_1+aya_2+bxa_2+ a_(2 ) a_3+bva_3+ cxa_3+ava_4+dxa_4$

Following the same process with the rest of the equation givs:

$axa_1+aya_2+bxa_2+ aza_3+bva_3+ cxa_3+ava_4+dxa_4= axa_1+aya_2+aza_3+ ava_4+ aa_1 x+ba_2 x+ca_3 x+ da_4 x$

When we cancel out terms on either side, we get 
$bva_3=aa_1 x$.

If we remember,all $a,b,c,d,x,y,z,v Є R$, we can substitute and solve to further simplify the equation. If we set $a=0$, we then get that $a_1=a_3=0$
Taking our equation $f(a,b,c,d)=aa_1+ba_2+ca_3+da_4$, and substituting in our zero values, we are left with $f(a,b,c,d)=ba_2+da_4$. We can use our new information to simplify the other 3 equations. Let us begin with equation 2.

Equation 2:  Using the same process as above, we will begin to simplify equation 2: $g(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=$ $ag(x,y,z,v)+bf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)y+g(a,b,c,d)x$

If we assign $g(1,0,0,0)=b_1,  g(0,1,0,0)=b_2, g(0,0,1,0)=b_3, g(0,0,0,1)=b_4$,

we get $axb_1+ayb_2+bxb_2+azb_3+bvb_3+cxb_3+avb_4+dxb_4= axb_1+ayb_2+azb_3+avb_4+ bxa_1+bya_2+bza_3+bva_4+ aya_1+bya_2+cya_3+dya_4+ axb_1+bxb_2+cxb_3+dxb_4$

Canceling out terms on either side and also canceling out any terms that have $a_1$ and $a_3$ since they equal 0, we get:

$bvb_3=bya_2+bva_4+bya_2+dya_4+axb_1$

If we have $b=0$ and $a=0$, then we are left with $0=dya_4$, therefore $a_4=0$
$bvb_3=bya_2+bva_4+bya_2+dya_4+axb_1$

Taking the same equation and setting  $b=0$ and $v=0$, we then have $0=axb_1$, therefore $b_1=0$

$bvb_3=bya_2+bva_4+bya_2+dya_4+axb_1$

Once again taking the same equation, this time setting $b=1$ and $v=0$, gives us $0=2ya_2$, therefore, $a_2=0$

$bvb_3=bya_2+bva_4+bya_2+dya_4+axb_1$ and once again taking the same equation, this time just canceling out all the terms that are equal to 0, gives us $0=bvb_3$, which means that $b_3=0$ Giving us $g(a,b,c,d)=ab_1+bb_2+cb_3+db_4=bb_2+db_4$

So far, we have solved and gotten that  $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$ and  $b_1=b_2=0$ . If we apply this to equation 1: $f(a,b,c,d)=ba_2+da_4$, we now have $f(a,b,c,d)=0$

Equation 3: $h(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=ah(x,y,z,v)+bi(x,y,z,v)+cf(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)z+g(a,b,c,d)v+h(a,b,c,d)x$

Using the same process as above and assigning  $h(1,0,0,0)=c_1,  h(0,1,0,0)=c_2, h(0,0,1,0)=c_3, h(0,0,0,1)=c_4$, and if we assign $i(1,0,0,0)=d_1,  i(0,1,0,0)=d_2, i(0,0,1,0)=d_3, i(0,0,0,1)=d_4$ we then have the following equation:

Equation 3 is now $axc_1+ayc_2+bxc_2+azc_3+bvc_3+cxc_3+avc_4+dxc_4= axc_1+ayc_2+azc_3+avc_4+ bxd_1+byd_2+bzd_3+bvd_4+ cxa_1+cya_2+cza_3+cva_4+aza_1+bza_2+cza_3+dza_4+ avb_1+avb_2+cvb_3+dvb_4+ axc_1+bxc_2+cxc_3+dxc_4$

Canceling out all terms gives 
$bvc_3= bxd_1+byd_2+bzd_3+bvd_4+avb_2+axc_1+dvb_4$
If we assign $b=0$ and $a=0$, we then have $0=dvb_4$, so therefore $b_4=0$

Taking the same equation 
$bvc_3= bxd_1+byd_2+bzd_3+bvd_4+avb_2+axc_1+dvb_4$ and now setting $b=0$ and $v=0$, we have $c_1=0$

$bvc_3= bxd_1+byd_2+bzd_3+bvd_4+avb_2+axc_1+dvb_4$ Taking this equation once again, and deleting the last two terms since we now know that they are 0,  gives us $bvc_3= bxd_1+byd_2+bzd_3+bvd_4+avb_2$ and if we set $b=0$, we now get $0=avb_2$, which tells us that$ b_2=0$

Now, taking Equation 2 from above $g(a,b,c,d)=ab_1+bb_2+cb_3+db_4=bb_2+db_4$, we now know that $g(a,b,c,d)=0$

$h(a,b,c,d)=ac_1+bc_2+cc_3+dc_4=bc_2+cc_3+dc_4$
Equation 4: $i(ax,ay+bx,az+bv+cx,av+dx)=ai(x,y,z,v)+df(x,y,z,v)+f(a,b,c,d)v+i(a,b,c,d)x$ .
Using the same process as above to simplify Equation 4, we get:

$axd_1+ayd_2+bxd_2+azd_3+bvd_3+avd_4+dxd_4=axd_1+ayd_2+azd_3+avd_4+dxa_1+dya_2+dza_3+dva_4+dxa_1+dya_2+dza_3+dva_4+ava_1+bva_2+cva_3+dva_4 axd_1+bxd_2+cxd_3+dxd_4$

Canceling out all terms gives 
$bvd_3=axd_1+cxd_3$
If we set $x=0$, we get $d_3=$0 And if $d_3=0$, then $d_1=0$
$i(a,b,c,d)=ad_1+bd_2+cd_3+dd_4=bd_2+ dd_4$

In my conclusion, I have that

$f(a,b,c,d)=0$

$g(a,b,c,d=0$

$h(a,b,c,d)=bc_2+cc_3+dc_4$

$i(a,b,c,d)=dd_4$

Comment: The answer in the previous question is hinting at the fact that $d(Id) = 0$ for any derivation $d$.  This applies here, so, by linearity, you may assume $a = 0$.

Comment: Now, I have had a few negative remarks on this questions, and I am not sure why. I have spent a lot of time on this and shown a lot of research. I've had professors look my work over so far without question. My work is very detailed, I even deleted some of so that this question was not as lengthy, which says a lot considering how lengthy it still is. If there is a better way to show this work, let me know. Just please keep in mind, I am a detail, step by step oriented person, so please explain your process if you wish to change methods on me.

Comment: I guess the first sentence makes quite some people stop reading your question (the length is also intimidating). "$DT_3(R)$ is the upper triangular matrix with the diagonal being the same element" cannot be correct, as "the" indicates that there is only one. It should be "a". But then reading on, one gets to know that $DT_3(R)$ is meant to be **the set of all** $3\times3$ matrices whose diagonal elements are all the same. By the way, is $R$ any ring or the ring/field $\mathbb R$ of the real numbers?

Comment: @j.p., it is the real field. I cleaned up the questions a bit as well

Comment: It's just my opinion, but one of the reason for negative marks might be complicated approach and notation (but it's just a guess).  It's not that easy to follow lengthy notation. Using the ring structure and properties of $DT_3 (\mathbb{R})$ and properties of $d$ helps a lot to make things way less lengthy.

Comment: @cele: Hi cele. I have absolute respect for your courage in pursuing this lengthy argument. I tried to follow it to the very end, but somewhere in the middle, it became quite dense and I lost my focus. Lengthy arguments tend to contain subtle errors. For example, you obtained $ g(a,b,c,d) = 0 $, which I don’t think is correct. In my answer below, I obtained a non-zero function for the $ (1,2) $-entry, which I proceeded to verify at the end. Your approach is fine, but many people might consider it too ‘brute-force’. I hope I’m not upsetting you with my frankness!

Comment: @BerrickFillmore, not at all. Even I began to question the validity of my approach and did recognize that errors could very well be likely. I was just unsure on how else I should approach the problem, thus the need for assistance. I thank you for your comments and help.

Comment: @cele: You’re most welcome! I totally understand that some people here on Math Stack Exchange appear a little ‘unfriendly’, but I guess that’s just the way it is in the real world. By the way, I hope you wouldn’t mind my edit. I removed the ‘derivatives’ tag because it refers to differentiation rather than algebraic derivations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pardon me for elaborating on loup blanc’s solution for cele’s benefit here; my elaboration would simply be too long for a comment.

---

For any $ A,B,C,D \in \Bbb{R} $, we have
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix}
= A \underbrace
    {\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{I_{3}} +
  B \underbrace
    {\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{E_{12}} +
  C \underbrace
    {\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{E_{13}} +
  D \underbrace
    {\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{E_{23}}.
$$
The matrices $ I_{3} $, $ E_{12} $, $ E_{13} $ and $ E_{23} $ thus form a basis for the $ \Bbb{R} $-vector space $ {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) $. Note also that $ {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) $ is an **$ \Bbb{R} $-algebra** under matrix multiplication.

Conditions $ (1) $, $ (2) $ and $ (3) $ say that the map $ d: {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) \to {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) $ is a **derivation**, i.e., a linear transformation that obeys the Leibniz Rule.

We know from linear algebra that a linear transformation is entirely determined by its values on a vector-space basis. Hence, $ d $, being a linear transformation, is entirely determined by its values on $ I_{3} $, $ E_{12} $, $ E_{13} $ and $ E_{23} $.

In what follows, $ \bullet $ shall denote matrix multiplication.

---

Firstly,
$$
  d(I_{3})
= d(I_{3} \bullet I_{3})
= I_{3} \bullet d(I_{3}) + d(I_{3}) \bullet I_{3}
= 2 \cdot d(I_{3}),
$$
which gives us $ d(I_{3}) = \mathbf{0}_{3} $.

---

Secondly,
$$
  d(E_{12} \bullet E_{12})
= E_{12} \bullet d(E_{12}) + d(E_{12}) \bullet E_{12}.
$$
However, $ E_{12} \bullet E_{12} = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, so $ d(E_{12} \bullet E_{12}) = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, which yields
$$
(\clubsuit) \qquad E_{12} \bullet d(E_{12}) = - d(E_{12}) \bullet E_{12}.
$$
Suppose that $ d(E_{12}) = \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix} $. Then $ (\clubsuit) $ implies that
\begin{align}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \\
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, $ D = 0 $ and $ A = - A $, which also gives us $ A = 0 $. Therefore,
$$
d(E_{12}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B & C \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

Thirdly,
$$
  d(E_{13} \bullet E_{13})
= E_{13} \bullet d(E_{13}) + d(E_{13}) \bullet E_{13}.
$$
However, $ E_{13} \bullet E_{13} = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, so $ d(E_{13} \bullet E_{13}) = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, which yields
$$
(\spadesuit) \qquad E_{13} \bullet d(E_{13}) = - d(E_{13}) \bullet E_{13}.
$$
Suppose that $ d(E_{13}) = \begin{bmatrix} A' & B' & C' \\ 0 & A' & D' \\ 0 & 0 & A' \end{bmatrix} $. Then $ (\spadesuit) $ implies that
\begin{align}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0  & 1  \\ 0 & 0  & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} A' & B' & C' \\ 0 & A' & D' \\ 0 & 0 & A' \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix} A' & B' & C' \\ 0 & A' & D' \\ 0 & 0 & A' \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0  & 1  \\ 0 & 0  & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}, \\
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & A' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & A' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, $ A' = - A' $, which gives us $ A' = 0 $. Therefore,
$$
d(E_{13}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B' & C' \\ 0 & 0 & D' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

Fourthly,
$$
  d(E_{23} \bullet E_{23})
= E_{23} \bullet d(E_{23}) + d(E_{23}) \bullet E_{23}.
$$
However, $ E_{23} \bullet E_{23} = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, so $ d(E_{23} \bullet E_{23}) = \mathbf{0}_{3} $, which yields
$$
(\heartsuit) \qquad E_{23} \bullet d(E_{23}) = - d(E_{23}) \bullet E_{23}.
$$
Suppose that $ d(E_{23}) = \begin{bmatrix} A'' & B'' & C'' \\ 0 & A'' & D'' \\ 0 & 0 & A'' \end{bmatrix} $. Then $ (\heartsuit) $ implies that
\begin{align}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}
      A'' & B'' & C'' \\ 0 & A'' & D'' \\ 0 & 0 & A''
      \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix}
      A'' & B'' & C'' \\ 0 & A'' & D'' \\ 0 & 0 & A''
      \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \\
      \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0   \\ 0 & 0 & A'' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
& = - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & B'' \\ 0 & 0 & A'' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, $ B'' = 0 $ and $ A'' = - A'' $, which also gives us $ A'' = 0 $. Therefore,
$$
d(E_{23}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & C'' \\ 0 & 0 & D'' \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

Organizing the information that we have, we find that there exist $ p,q,r,s,t,u,v \in \Bbb{R} $ such that
\begin{align}
d(E_{12}) & = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\\
d(E_{13}) & = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & r & s \\ 0 & 0 & t \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\\
d(E_{23}) & = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & u \\ 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
We proceed to show that $ r = t = 0 $ and $ s = p + v $.

---

Observe that
$$
  d((E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet (E_{12} + E_{23}))
= (E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet d(E_{12} + E_{23}) +
  d(E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet (E_{12} + E_{23}).
$$
However, $ (E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet (E_{12} + E_{23}) = E_{13} $, so
$$
  d(E_{13})
= (E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet d(E_{12} + E_{23}) +
  d(E_{12} + E_{23}) \bullet (E_{12} + E_{23}).
$$
This implies that
\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 & r & s \\ 0 & 0 & t \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
& = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0     \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q + u \\ 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q + u \\ 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0     \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
    \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & p \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & p + v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, $ r = t = 0 $ and $ s = p + v $.

---

We now have a more complete description of $ d $, namely, there exist $ p,q,u,v \in \Bbb{R} $ such that
\begin{align}
d(E_{12}) & = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\\
d(E_{13}) & = \begin{bmatrix}
              0 & 0 & p + v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
              \end{bmatrix}, \\
d(E_{23}) & = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & u \\ 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

---

Finally, to show that $ p $, $ q $, $ u $ and $ v $ have no more interdependence, consider
$$
M =  \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
M' = \begin{bmatrix} A' & B' & C' \\ 0 & A' & D' \\ 0 & 0 & A' \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
    d(M)
& = A \cdot d(I_{3}) + B \cdot d(E_{12}) + C \cdot d(E_{13}) + D \cdot d(E_{23})\\
& = A \cdot \mathbf{0}_{3} +
    B \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q     \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
    C \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & p + v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
    D \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & u     \\ 0 & 0 & v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & B p & B q + C (p + v) + D u \\ 0 & 0 & D v \\ 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Similarly, $ d(M') = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B' p & B' q + C' (p + v) + D' u \\ 0 & 0 & D' v \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $. Next, observe that
\begin{align}
M \bullet d(M') & = \begin{bmatrix}
                    0 & A B' p & A B' q + A C' (p + v) + A D' u + B D' v \\
                    0 & 0      & A D' v \\
                    0 & 0      & 0
                    \end{bmatrix}, \\
d(M) \bullet M' & = \begin{bmatrix}
                    0 & A' B p & B D' p + A' B q + A' C (p + v) + A' D u \\
                    0 & 0      & A' D v \\
                    0 & 0      & 0
                    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
M \bullet d(M') + d(M) \bullet M' = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & (A B' + A' B) p & (A B' + A' B) q + (A C' + A' C + B D') (p + v) +
                      (A D' + A' D) u \\
0 & 0               & (A D' + A' D) v \\
0 & 0               & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
As
$$
M \bullet M' = \begin{bmatrix}
               A A' & A B' + A' B & A C' + A' C + B D' \\
               0    & A A'        & A D' + A' D \\
               0    & 0           & A A'
               \end{bmatrix},
$$
we obtain
$$
d(M \bullet M') = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & (A B' + A' B) p & (A B' + A' B) q + (A C' + A' C + B D') (p + v) +
                      (A D' + A' D) u \\
0 & 0               & (A D' + A' D) v \\
0 & 0               & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as well. Therefore, $ d(M \bullet M') = M \bullet d(M') + d(M) \bullet M' $ without any further hypotheses.

---

**Conclusion:** A map $ d: {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) \to {\text{DT}_{3}}(\Bbb{R}) $ is a derivation if and only if there exist scalars $ p $, $ q $, $ u $ and $ v $ such that
$$
  d \!
  \left( \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \\ 0 & A & D \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix} \right)
= \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & B p & B q + C (p + v) + D u \\ 0 & 0 & D v \\ 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

By linearity, it suffices to know $d(I_3),d(E_{1,3}),d(E_{1,2}),d(E_{2,3})$. Jason proved that $d(I_3)=0$. It is not difficult, but not very funny, to show that $d(E_{1,3})=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&q+v\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $d(E_{1,2})=\begin{pmatrix}0&v&w\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $d(E_{2,3})=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&p\\0&0&q\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ where $p,q,v,w$ are arbitrary numbers.

Use $E_{1,2}^2=E_{1,3}^2=E_{2,3}^2=0_3$ and $(E_{1,2}+E_{2,3})^2=E_{1,3}$.

EDIT. It is not difficult to see that $d$ is a derivation over $T_3$ (the set of upper triangular matrices) that satisfies $d=0$ over the diagonal matrices. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, it is well-known that a derivation over $T_n$ is inner. Here $d=\delta_U:X\rightarrow UX-XU$ where $U=\begin{pmatrix}0&p&0\\0&-v&-w\\0&0&-v-q\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $U\notin DT_3$.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a little further how you got to this? I am not clearly seeing the connection following my work to yours.

Comment: Forget your work. Put $E_{1,2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $d(E_{1,2})=\begin{pmatrix}u&v&w\\0&u&x\\0&0&u\end{pmatrix}$. For instance $E_{1,2}^2=0$ implies $0=d(E_{1,2})E_{1,2}+E_{1,2}d(E_{1,2})$.

Comment: It is a well-known notation. $E_{i,j}$ denotes the matrix with all entries zero except the one in position (i, j) which is $1$.

Comment: though I believe your answer to be current, I just do not understand it. I have focused so much on my line of work for it, that your version does not correlate with me. How did you get to your answers? How did you start the work off?

Comment: @ cele , if you use my comment above, you find that $E_{1,2}^2=0$ implies $u=x=0$. In the same way, you find that $E_{2,3}^2=0$ implies that $d(E_{2,3})=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&p\\0&0&q\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Finally $E_{1,2}E_{2,3}=E_{1,3}$ implies that $d(E_{1,3})=E_{1,2}d(E_{2,3})+d(E_{1,2})E_{2,3}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&q+v\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. It remains to show the converse...